# Benefits of devi 'Durga' naam jap with proofs scriptural reference from sāshtras

Tags: scripture, durga, sadhana, japa

I want to know the benefits and results of chanting Durgâ name only. Can we chant Durgâ name without *guru dikșha*?

And, what if I chant it constantly for some years? Can I get *siddhi* from it? Will my *tapobalam* increase?
Please give me *śhlokas* from scriptures about it.

Answer (score 10):

The name 'Durga' is a two lettered mantra and performing its japa is highly beneficial. In **Maya-Tantra, 5-th Patala** Shiva tells its benifits:

> धन्यं यशस्यामायुष्यं प्रजापुष्टिविवर्द्धनम्‌।
> सहस्त्रनामाभिस्तुल्यं दुर्गानामवरानने॥3॥

> Reciting the *Durga nama* provides wealth, success and longevity. It gives *Santanik-Sukha* (offspring), and its equal to one thousand names. (3)

> महापदि महादुर्गे आयुषो नाशमागते।
> जातिध्वंसे कुलोच्छेदे महानिगडबन्धने॥4॥
> व्याधिशरीरसम्पाते दुश्चिकित्सामयेऽपि वा।
> शत्रुभिः समनुप्राप्ते बन्धुभिस्त्यक्तसौहदे।5॥
> **जपेद्‌ दुर्गायुतं नाम ततस्तस्मात्‌ प्रमुच्यते।**
> दुर्गेति मङ्गलं नाम यस्य चेतसि वर्तते॥6॥
> स मुक्तो देवि संसारात्‌ स नम्यः सुरकैरपि।
> **दुर्गेति द्व्यक्षरं मन्त्रं** जपतो नास्ति पातकम्‌॥7॥

> He must take the name of *Durga* when he is in a great Challenging situation, when his longevity is in danger, when the race is in danger, when the '*kula*' is devastated, when he is struck in the 'net' (4). He must take the name of Durga when he is recovering, when he is suffering from a disease, when the enemy surrounds him, when siblings dont support him. (5) The one who always keeps reciting the name of Durga, he gets *mukti* from this *samasara*, and even gets worshiped by devi herself. Performing the *japa* of this two syllabled *Mantra* clears all the sins.(6,7)

The tantra says one must chant the name before staring any work:

> कार्यारम्भे स्मरेद्‌ यस्तु तस्य सिद्धिरदूरतः।
> दुर्गेति नाम जप्तव्यं कोटिमात्रं सुरेश्वरि॥8॥

> one achieves success by taking the name before initiating the work. One must take the name of *Durga* for one crore times. (8)

Also, the time of Eclipse is excellent for its japa. However one must not count the number of japas done during an eclipse:

> गणनं सस्‍नानदानादौ न जपे परमेश्वारि।
> रवीन्द्वो्ग्रहणे पृथ्व्यां जपतुल्या न च क्रिया॥4॥
> तस्मात्‌ सर्व परित्यज्य जपमात्र॑ समाचरेत्‌।
> तेनैव सर्वसिद्धिः स्थाज्नात्र कार्या विचचारणा॥5॥

> No count must be kept on the baths, donation and japa. There is nothing more significant, than taking the nama during eclipse. (4) Thus, forgetting about everything else, let him just take the nama. He will get all types of *siddhis* just by taking the nama.(5)

- Without a Guru, No sadhanas attain a completion. However I believe, one must chant the name even if he is not initiated.

---

The tantra provides the details of its [purascharan](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17177/21353): Japa for one crore times, its 1/10-th must go to a Homa I.e. a homa with 10 lakh Aahuties, its 1/10-th in Tarpans I.e. 1 lakh tarpans, its 1/10-th in Abhishekam and feeding the Brahmins I.e. Abhishekam and feeding Brahmins for 1 lakh times. The tantra says if this cant be done, the japa must be done for **two crore times**.

Comment: Lots of thanks for giving these knowledges Sir!

Answer (score 4):

The mahima of Durga naam can't even be told by Shiv in tantras. He says thus,

> दुर्गानाम जपो यस्य किं तस्य कथयामि ते।
> अहम् पंचैननह् कांते तज्जपादेवसुव्रते।।
> Oh, devi how could I narate he glory of the name 'Durga'? It is of the recitation of the Durga Naam that I am called panchanan.

Imagine, Shiv himself says that it is by chanting of Durganaam that he is called Panchavaktra(The one with 5 faces). Now the name **Panchanana** is highlighting in itself. It is from these 5 faces that Shiv established the 5 Anmayas and gave Tantra, Agamas, Shastras etc. Thus Mahadev credits it all to durga naam, and it's japa. Indirectly he point out that, it's by Durga naam that he created so many scriptures.

Mahadev says in other tantra that,

> श्रृणुदेवी वरारोहे ममैव निश्चितं वचह्।
> विना दुर्गा परिज्ञानाद विफलं पूजनं जपह्।।
> दुर्गा हि परमो मंत्र दुर्गा हि परमोजपह्।
> दुर्गा हि परमं तीर्थम दुर्गा हि परमह् क्रिया।।
> दुर्गा हि परमा भक्तीदुर्गा मूर्तिमहितले
> बुद्धिनिद्रक्षुधा छाया शक्तिस्तृष्णा तथा क्षमा।
> Oh boon giver Devi! Listen to my infallible words. Without the knowledge of Durga, one's pooja and Japa bear no fruits. Durga is supreme Mantra, Durga is supreme Japa. Durga is the supreme Tirth and the supreme Kriya. She is also the nature of supreme Bhakti on the nature of highest Mukti on this earth. Intellect, sleep, hungry, veil, energy, forgiveness,Mercy,certainty, peace, prosperity and memory. All of them are verily Durga not different from her that's why recite always the name Durga.

Thus fruis of recitations are as follows-

> धनी पुत्री तथान्यानि चिरंजीवी भवेभ्दुवि।
> प्रत्यहं यो जपेद भक्तया शतम् अष्टोत्तरं शुचिह्।।
> One who recites the name of Durga 108 times everyday, is blessed with prosperity offspring wisdom and longevity.

> दुर्गा नाम जापात पापं सर्व्वय्याति हि ततक्षणात।
> वेदास्वागमतंत्रेषु पुराणेषु सुनिश्चिम।।
> दुर्गा नाम समाख्यातंा चतुर्वेदविदंा मतम्
> By recitation of the name Durga all sins get destroyed it is ascertained by Vedas, Agam, Tantra and Puranas, verily Durga Naam is embodiment of four Vedas.

> दुर्गा दुर्गेति दुर्गेति दुर्गानाम पर मनुम् ।                             यो भजेत् सततं चण्डि! जीवन्मुक्तः स मानवः ॥                           महोत्पाते महारोगे महाविपदि सङ्कटे ।                                       महादुःखे महाशेके महाभये समुत्थिते ॥                                      यः सदा संस्मरेद् दुर्गा यो जपेत् परमं मनुम् ।                          स जीवलोके देवेशि ! नीलकण्ठत्वमाप्नुयात् ।।
> Śrī Śiva: Durga, Durga Durga- This Durga name is the best mantra. Hey Chandi! the human who always worships this mantra, that human life gets liberated. In great distress, in great disease, in great calamity, in great sorrow, in the presence of great fear, one who always remembers Durga, who chants the best of Durga's mantra, O Goddess! In the world of mortal life, he gets benefited with Neelkanthatvā.
> -Mundāmālā Tantrā

> यन्नाम संस्मरन् शम्भुः पिबन् हालाहलं परम्
> विजित्य मृत्युं लोकेऽस्मिन्नाम्ना मृत्युञ्जयोऽभवत् ॥
> By Remembering Durga's Name, Lord Śankarā became famous in this world by the name of Mrītyunjayā, having conquered death even after drinking the terrible Poison (Halahala).

**कालिकार्पणमास्तु ।**

Comment: Kya Durga nam jap ke lia deeksha ki jarurat hai? kyuki tantra shastra mei diksha ke bina mantra jap ka koi fal nahi milta aesa bataya jata hai.

Answer (score 1):

One can get worldly pleasures from Durga naam japa as per [enter link description here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225984.html)

> 43-45. O lordly sage, she came to be called by various names such as Kālī, Caṇḍikā, Cāmuṇḍā, Vijayā, Jayā, Jayantī, Bhadrakālī, **Durgā**, Bhagavatī, Kāmākhyā, Kāmadā, Ambā, Mṛḍānī and Sarvamaṅgalā. **These various names confer worldly pleasures and salvation according to qualities and action.** The name Pārvatī is very common.