# Is any god name eligible for nama japa?

Tags: scripture, gods, name, goddess, japa

Although, in general, it takes more time than mantra japa to achieve results in nama japa, nama japa is a great path for all people in Kaliyuga.

It is extremely simple and needs no strict rules and regulations. If we opt for mantra japa, yoga, upasanas, etc., there are so many rules on food, sleep, behavior, etc., and also needs some guru. But, if we opt for nama japa, it is free for all.

#1: [It does not need initiation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32539/661)

#2: No need to follow strict rules and regulations

> One who chants the holy name of the Lord is immediately freed from the
> reactions of unlimited sins, even if he chants **indirectly, jokingly, for musical entertainment, or even
> neglectfully**. This is accepted by all the learned scholars of the
> scriptures.
>
> [[ŚB 6.2.14]](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/6/2/14/)

And it also assures the darshan of God.

In scriptures, we generally read the mentions about the capabilities/powers of some names only. The names include 'Shiva', 'Rama', 'Krishna', 'Hari' etc. So, I got the following doubt.

Is it the case with any name of any god and goddess? Suppose there are sahastranamas for gods and goddesses, if I take a single name from them and I keep on reciting them, then will it give the same result ultimately?

Note that the time span to experience results may be different for different names, but the question is not on that. The question is only about the final result by doing nama japa on a selected name.

Comment: On the level from which you seem to be Asking, how could it not be clear that   any god name is eligible…?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin But, I am searching for a reference.

Comment: Fine, and why are you searching for that reference here, rather than through your search engine of choice? Do you not think SE Hinduism is a place to come to after you've explained how your general search engines ran out of ideas?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Experts can provide references from scriptures that I am unaware of.

Comment: How could it help that experts could provide references of which you were unaware? Can you usefully provide any references, or not?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin sanathan dharma is not dependent on a single book like many other religions. I can cover some only. So it is infeasible for me to check all. It is a forum for service not for just rewards I think.

Comment: So again, you want others to do the research for you? What kind of karma is that?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin some experts already did their research in this area and experienced the bliss by realizing the facts. And they transfer knowledge. It is divine karma. That's why we treat knowledge as saras (continuously flowing)...

Comment: Why not go back to where you're searching for a reference, and make that search through your chosen search engines. How hard could that be?

You're entitled to seek Answers from members here, and does that mean it's fair to ask them to do your work? 

From 10 Oct, how long will you persist in avoiding useful statements?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin in sanathan dharma, sharing knowledge is not treated as a burden or even a duty. And it is known that SE sites are meant for the same.

Comment: Sorry, Hanugm; "it is known that SE sites are meant for the same" is clearly stated all over SE to be the polar opposite of your interpretation.

The idea is, you do some research then Post the results and Ask about whatever conclusions remain unclear to you.

How is that hard for anyone?
 
If you can't be bothered to do your own research, who just now told us "sharing knowledge is not treated as… even a duty"?

Sharing knowledge should indeed not be a burden and do you see no difference between leaches, parasites and their like, and students prepared to work for their rewards?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin It should be treated as responsibility...

Comment: Hanugm Have you no responsibility, as for basic research, whatever burden you're happy to impose on others? Again, do you see no difference between students prepared to work for their rewards and parasites? Again, when you're searching for references why not show what efforts you've made, and how far they got?

Again, that's what Stack Exchange is for… as clearly opposed to simply Asking initial Questions, whether you see that as begging/demanding/looking for/requesting or hoping that Members will fulfil what you see as their Karmic responsibility.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I feel responsible and hence I keep answers also if I'm aware with.  If anyone feels like a burden, there are always allowed to not provide an answer. A guru never treats sishya as a burden. BTW, I showed all the information I know and asked for generalized references.

Answer (score 8):

From **Third Samas-Fourth Dashak** of **Shree Dasbodh** by **Samartha Ramdas**,

Majority of the part explains the benefits and importance of "Rama-nama", but the following two verses are more generally applicable.

> परमेश्वराची अनंत नामें। स्मस्तां तरिजे नित्यनेमें।
> नामस्मरण करितां येमें। बाधिजेना ॥१९॥
>
> > There are infinite names of the Param-ishvara, taking any name from them to chant brings salvation. By taking the nama he doesn't need to suffer the yama-yatana (suffering after death).

> सहस्रा नामामथ्यें कोणी येक | म्हणतां होतसे सार्थक।
> नाम स्मस्तां पुण्यश्त्मेक | होईजे स्वयें. ॥२०॥
>
> > Taking any name from the thousand names of the God brings immense benefits. He who takes the name continuously with faith becomes a nobel soul (Punyatma).

Taking names like "Rama", "Shiva", "Krishna" is very common. Other than these names, Maya tantra describes benifits of "[Durga-Nama](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48330/21353)".

Comment: It is a great benefit for people in Kali Yuga.