# Which name of Lord Krishna is suggested for repetition in the scriptures?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, japa, nama-japa

Which name of Lord Krishna is suggested for repetition in the scriptures, for continuous Nama Japa in the mind at all times (including while eating, sleeping, in the restroom etc) as ajapa japa?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51746/is-any-god-name-eligible-for-nama-japa

Comment: Do not all the names of Sri Krishna remind you of him? Pick the one that your mind likes best......

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're Asking which name is suggested for repetition in the scriptures, from whatever source, or is suggested by the scriptures for repetition any or everywhere? Else, why not go with the Swami above?

Comment: The sound produced by every name of Krishna has Lord Vishnu residing in the Sound, So Choose any one name and Recite it

Answer (score 2):

There are many names of Krishanji given in the [Vishnu Sahasranaam](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/vishnu/Sri.Vishnu.Sahasaranam.pdf), including Krishna, **Shikhaṃḍī** (Incarnation as Lord Krishna with a peacock feather embedded in his crown), **Śauriḥ** (Krishna who incarnated in the dynasty of Shoora), **Gōpatiḥ** (Krishna who tends the cattle in the form of a Gopa) and **Devakī-nandanaḥ** (The Son of Devaki in the incarnation as Krishna).

Lord Shiva's opinion is that **Raam Naam is superior to all of them**:

> श्री राम राम रामेित रमे रामे मनोरमे। सहस्रनाम तत्तुल्यं राम नाम वरानने॥ २७॥

He says chanting Raam Naam gives benefit of **all of them combined**. I can't find the source of this but it is also given in other purans (including Shaiv Purans) that Shivji always chants Raam Naam only. No other name. Now if you think Raam and Krishanji are different please check Vedic scripture [Krishna Upanishad](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/vedicsection/upanishads/krishna.asp):

> [Raamji says] When I **reincarnate as Lord Krishna**

So **Krishna is nothing but Shri Raam** himself.

As per Vedas and Dev Adi-dev Bhagvaan Mahadev Shiv you should only chant Raam Naam for maximum benefit. To my knowledge this is no restriction and you can do this at all times.

Answer (score 2):

ऋगवेददेऽथ यजुर्वेद तथैवार्थव सामसु।

पुराणे सोपनिषदि तथैव ज्योतिषेऽर्जुन।

साख्ये च योगशास्त्रे च आयुर्वेदे तथैव च।

बहुनि मम नामानि कीर्तितानि च महर्षिभिः।

गौणानि तत्र नामानि कर्मज्ञानि च कानि च।

सर्वेसु मंत्र तत्वेषु रामनाम परात्परम्।।

Mahabharata Shanti parv chapter 350  shlok 8,9 &10

Shri Krishna says:- वेद, उपनिषद, पुराण, सांख्य, ज्योतिष, योग, इत्यादि सद्ग्रंथ शास्त्र में ब्रह्म के बहुत सारे नाम है , परन्तु उन सब भगवान नाम और मंत्र , महामंत्र में श्रीराम  नाम परात्पर है।

Shri Krishna says:- There are many names of Brahm in Vedas, Upanishads, Puranas, Samkhya, Astrology, Yoga, etc. scriptures, but in all those God names and mantras, the name of Shri Ram is supreme.