# Who are these goddesses in the pictures?

Tags: identification-request, goddess

I found this pictures in Instagram. Who are these goddesses? Is any mention of these goddesses in Hindu Puranas?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you also give the instagram links?

Comment: The first one is Jayadurga. Can't say about the 2nd one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about postings on social media should be directed to the authors of those postings. This is not a forum to clarify social media postings

Comment: @Rickross the instagram link is here: https://www.instagram.com/p/CCcLr46lROn/?utm_medium=share_sheethttps://www.instagram.com/p/CCzChXIF5ZG/?utm_medium=share_sheet

Comment: Thanks for the link @BoovanaesS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Who are these goddesses?
```

**1. Jayadurga

2. Bhuvaneshwari**

Both of these devis are once again none other than 2 mahavidyas out of the 700 mahavidyas, the 2 shaktis of 13 Shaktis associated with the 13 chapters of Durga Saptashati. Also this both devis are included in the AngaVidya of Navarna Chandi. And are also the independent Mahavidyas and have their own lokas. Bhuvaneshwari resides in Manidweep & Durga resides in Durga loka.

```
Is any mention of these goddesses in Hindu Puranas?
```

Yes, these both devis are extremely famous amongst Shakti upasakas.

The first Devi is **Jaya Durga** devi, the ruling deity of the 4th chapter of Madhyam Charitra off Durga saptshati.
Her dhyanam is as follow-

> ॐ कालाभ्राभां कटाक्षैररिकुलभयदां मौलिबद्धेन्दुरेखां
> शड्‌खं चक्रं कृपाणं त्रिशिखमपि करैरुद्वहन्तीं त्रिनेत्राम्।
> सिंहस्कन्धाधिरूढां त्रिभुवनमखिलं तेजसा पूरयन्तीं
> ध्यायेद् दुर्गां जयाख्यां त्रिदशपरिवृतां सेवितां सिद्धिकामैः॥
> The Goddess, who is being worshipped by those men desiring for siddhi(attainment) and the devi, around whom, devas surround from all sides, meditate upon that Durga called **'Jaya'**. Her complexion is black like that of the dark clouds. Her eyes alone induces fear among the enemies. Her head is adorned with the brightness of moon. She holds, Shankha (conch), Chakra (Disc), Kripan (Sword) & Trishul (Trident). She has three eyes. She is riding on the shoulders of the lion, and covering all the three words with her effulgence.

PS- This is one of the 4 handed (chaturbhuji)form of Durga, called **Jayadurga** Devi who is Angavidya of Chandi.
When someone says about Durga, we assume her to be 8 handed and riding on a tiger. Which is absolutely wrong, since there are various type of Durgas, for example the one with two hands(Dwibhuji Mahishmardini), the one with eight hands that slayed Mahishasura (Ashtabhuji Simharudha), even Parvati Devi is called Durga because she slayed Durgamasura, Jatveda Durga that rules over Durga suktam of Mahanarayana Upanishad of the Krishna Yajurveda, Kirateshwari (Sabri) Durga, the wife of Kirat Avatar of Lord Siva, in which He tested Arjuna
Lord Siva became Kirat, and likewise many such more Durgas to go.

Thus, every durga mantra of stotra is dedicated to same devi is a misconception. Since we already know there are na na koti Durgas.

The second devi, is devi Bhuvaneshwari, the ruling deity of the 11th chapter of Durga Saptashati.
Her dhyana is as follows -

> ॐ बालरविद्युतिमिन्दुकिरीटां तुङ्‌गकुचां नयनत्रययुक्ताम्।
> स्मेरमुखीं वरदाङ्‌कुशपाशाभीतिकरां प्रभजे भुवनेशीम्॥
> I meditate upon Bhuvaneshwari Devi. Her complexion is that of the rising sun and has the moon as her diadem. She has heavy bosoms and three Eyes. She's smiling gently and displays, , Varda( boon giving), Ankush, Pasha & Abhaya (fear not) mudras.

(Ps- The form shown in painting is as per the dhyan used in Vamachar. It's just that the position of mudras & ayudhas shuffles, as compared to normal depicted images.)

Now there are endless other referances for Durga and Bhuvaneshwari across Puranas and tantras. Because Bhuvaneshwari devi is not just an Angavidya but is also a Mahavidya.
**To say the devi suktam is dedicated to Durga devi & the complete Shrimad Devi bhagwat mahapuran is dedicated to Bhuvaneshwari devi itself**
What to say else about their greatness.

Yet, if we observe closely, we see Durga devi is associated with the 4th chapter where devas euglogized her after she killed Mahishaura. Thus, she actually was Durga(the one who lifts her devotee from difficult situation) for the devas. Thus, to understand in same way those who worship Durga is liberated from all difficulties.
Even a durga naam is enough to burn sins, you can read my answer to Durga naam jaap [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51956/27796)

The second devi, **Bhuvaneshwari** is associated with the 11th chapter titled as Praises of Devi by devas, and the boons to them. In real sense Bhuvaneshwari devi is truly the granter of boons and that too very early. She is the only Kshipra siddhi Mahavidya (the Mahavidya that gets siddh very early). Also, she's Ati saumya. Expalining this Bhairava says in Rudrayamal,

> पुष्पाञ्जल्यष्टकं दद्यान्मूलेनैव पृथक् पृथक् ॥ २६            संवत्सरकृतायास्तु पूजायाः फलमाप्नुयात् ।
> प्रीतिमन्योऽन्यतः कृत्वा कमला निश्चला गृहे ॥ २७ ॥
> One must offer flowers and coagulated milk separately, as flower and food offerings to the Divine Mother to please and obtain Her blessings, in a timely manner.
> Doing so for a year and worshipping Her ardently, one will be able to obtain all the desired wishes and one will have everlasting wealth that will last several lifetimes. There will be no dearth of anything in the household of the devotee.

It takes lifetime for a sadhaka to even please the Siddhvidya leave alone Mahavidya. Here, the Bhairava says, just within one year the person shall obtain all desires, so truly isn't she a Kshipra prasanna Mahavidya !

Comment: Can you say who is the ruling deity of 10th chapter of Devi Mahatmya?

Comment: Ruling deity of Dasham Adhyaya is Bhagwati Kameshwari, who in herself is ShivaShaktiswaroopa.

Comment: Can you answer to my question? I give the link:- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53513/how-many-avatars-of-adi-shakti-in-kalika-purana-and-what-is-the-story-of-kubjika