Gayatri Purushcharan
I want to do Gayatri Purushcharan, I have taken diksha from Gayatri pariwar but it's difficult to get continuous guidance from them. I travel a lot. Where can I find a guide

The Guru, who has given the Diksha,should be the only guide for the disciple but general guidelines can be found in Swami Sivananda's book "Gayatri Japa":


GAYATRI PURASCHARANA
The Brahma-Gayatri-Mantra has twenty-four Aksharas. So, one Gayatri
Purascharana constitutes the repetition or Japa of 24 lakhs of times
of Gayatri Mantra. There are various rules for Purascharana. If you
repeat 3, 000 times daily, you should keep up the number daily all
throughout till you finish the full 24 lakhs. Cleanse the mirror of
Manas of its Mala and prepare the ground for the sowing of the
spiritual seed. His grace is very, very important.
The Maharashtrians are very fond of Gayatri Purascharana. There are in
Poona and other places persons who have performed Purascharana several
times. Sri Pandit Madan Mohan Malaviyaji was a votary of Gayatri
Purascharana. The success in his life and the establishment of a grand
Hindu University at Benares, is all attributable to his Gayatri Japa
and the benign Grace of the Blessed Mother Gayatri.
Swami Vidyaranya, the reputed author of the celebrated Panchadasi,
performed Gayatri Purascharana. Mother gave him Darshan and granted
Vidyaranya a boon. Swami Vidyaranya asked: "O Mother! There is a great
famine in the Deccan. Let there be a shower of gold to relieve the
immense distress of the people. " Accordingly there was a shower of
gold. Such is the power or Sakti of Gayatri Mantra.
Yoga-Bhrashtas and pure-minded persons only can have Darshan of
Gayatri by doing one Purascharana only. As the minds of vast majority
of persons in this Iron Age are filled with various sorts of
impurities, one has to do more than one Purascharana according to the
degree of impurity of the mind. The more the impurities, the greater
the number of Purascharana. The famous Madhusudana Swami did seventeen
Purascharanas of Krishna Mantra. He did not get Darshan of Lord
Krishna on account of the sins committed in killing 17 Brahmins in his
previous births. But he had Darshan of the Lord when he was on the
half way of the eighteenth Purascharana. The same rule applies to
Gayatri-Purascharana also.
HINTS ON GAYATRI-JAPA
In days of yore, Hindu ladies also used to wear sacred thread
(Yajnopavita) and repeat Gayatri. Manu was not in favour of this.
After the Purascharana is over, perform Havan and feed Brahmins,
Sadhus and poor people to propitiate the Goddess.
Those who wish to do Purascharana may live on milk and fruits. This
makes the mind Sattvic. One will derive great spiritual benefits.
There are no restrictions of any kind when you repeat a Mantra with
Nishkama Bhava for attaining Moksha. Restrictions or Vidhis come in
only when you want to get some fruits, when you do the Japa with
Sakama Bhava.
When a Purascharana of Gayatri is done on the banks of the Ganga
underneath an Asvattha tree or the Panchavriksha, Mantra-Siddhi comes
in rapidly.
If you repeat Gayatri 4, 000 times daily, you can finish the
Purascharana in one year, seven months and twenty-five days. If you do
the Japa slowly it will take 10 hours to finish 4, 000 daily. The same
number should be repeated daily.
You must observe strict Brahmacharya when you do Purascharana. Then
you can have Darshan of Gayatri easily. Those who are unable to
practise strict celibacy should be very moderate in copulation. This
is second best thing.
The practice of Akhanda Mauna (unbroken silence) during Purascharana
is highly beneficial. Those who are not able to practise this can
observe full Mauna for a week in a month or on Sundays.
Those who practise Purascharana should not get up from the Asana till
they finish the fixed number. They should not change the pose also.
Counting can be done through Maala, fingers or watch. Count the exact
number that you can do in one hour. Suppose you can do in one hour 400
Gayatri Mantras, then Japa for 10 hours means 10x400 =4, 000. There is
more concentration in counting through watch.
There are three varieties of Gayatri pictures for meditation in
morning, noon and evening. Many meditate on the five-faced Gayatri
only throughout the day.

Some other general rules and restrictions related to Mantra Purascharana can be found in this answer too: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17177/4732

Depends on the Beejaksharas given. It is one lakh Japa per Akshar:10 %of that Homa with Honey; 10% of that ,Feeding Vedaviths,10% of that Tharpan: 10 % of that Marjana.(:Source. Purascharan Kanda by Hayagriv as revealed in the poorva bhaga of Sri Lalitha Sahasranama and expanded by Sri Bhaskararaya in his commentary on Sree Lalitha Sahasranama)
Venkatramanan
